# UserName is Unknown when you Register

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing an application that has a problem. When you register, it doesn't actually know the `UserName`; it says it's undefined. I checked by alerting the `UserName` as soon as you register, and it says it's undefined. That's when I use the Angular way by doing `$scope.UserName`. When I do it the jQuery way `$("#userName")`, it works. How do I fix this?

Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qB3Gkeq5ji1YQyy0kpGH?p=preview).

Comment: Can you clean up that plunker with only the necessary files and controllers?

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NathanielFord i have another problem. Can you help me out in cloud9. Where we can do it collab? Please thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to pass the username, email and password into the function that's getting invoked when you click the submit button.

In controller:

```
$scope.createUser = function(username, email, password) {
    alert(username);
}
```

And in html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" ng-click="createUser(username, email, password)">
```

See the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7b9fxEhPAZlEAbFojC1t?p=preview

Comment: Chantu thank you so much. And it would be much appreciated if you could help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701475/how-to-make-global-variables-in-angular