# How to make global variables in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i have this problem where when you register you get to the Users page. And its suppose to say "Welcome " The username dosent show up for On The Webpage for reason im not to sure about... please help here is the plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qB3Gkeq5ji1YQyy0kpGH?p=preview

Please i need help..

i need to get some code for plunker so :
script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('LoginApp', ["firebase", "ngRoute"])

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'registration.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      })
      .when('/logIn', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      })

      .when('/User', {
        templateUrl: "User.html",
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });


  });


app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);


app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
  function($scope, Auth) {


      $scope.createUser = function() {

        $scope.message = null;
        $scope.error = null;
    var ref2 = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
  ref2.createUser({
    email: $scope.email,
    password: $scope.password
  }, function(error, userData) {
    if (error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
          alert("The new user account cannot be created because the email is already in use. Try to login");
          break;
        case "INVALID_EMAIL":
          alert("The specified email is not a valid email.");
          break;
        case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
          alert("The Specified Passowrd Is not valid.")
          break;
        default:
          alert("Error creating user:", error);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
      alert($scope.UserName)

      window.location.hash = "/User"
       $scope.usernames = "HEY"
    }
  });


      };

       $scope.logIn = function(){
        $scope.message = null;
        $scope.error = null;

        ref2.authWithPassword({
          "email" : $scope.logInemail,
          "password" : $scope.logInemailpassword

        }, function(error, userData){

          if(error){
            alert("Login Failed.")
            console.log(error)
          }
          else{
            alert("Logged In!")
          }

        })

      }

  /*  $scope.removeUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      Auth.$removeUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      }).then(function() {
        $scope.message = "User removed";
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });
    };*/
  }
]);
```

Comment: I guess you need to study more about angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide look for services and scope .

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes can you help me thoguh?

Comment: Sorry. this kind of question should be closed. There are several ways to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things in your code that you might want to take care of, but some quick and partially dirty solutions:

Do not include all of your javascript files on your nested templates. Anything that is routed to in your `ng-view` should just be the html you want to be inserted within that `<div>`. No CSS links, no script tags, nothing but HTML that would normally be within the body of a page.

On your registration page, your username `ng-model` needs to match what you are passing as an argument to your `ng-click`. So instead of `ng-model="userName"` you need it to be `ng-model="username"` to match `ng-click="createUser(username, email, password)"`.

Your other major issue is that `$scope` is being overwritten each time you change views because each one of your routes has the same controller. So conceptually, you may be thinking that the `username` (which you have stored as the plural `$scope.usernames` for some reason) is there for you to access still on `$scope`. But that is not the case, as each view is running on its own unique instance of the Auth Controller. The quickest solution since you don't know how to implement services is probably to inject `$rootScope` into your controller, and then put `usernames` on `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` (though keep in mind using `$rootScope` in production is considered bad practice), as $rootScope will persist across all of your controllers. So your javascript file would look more like this:

`app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "Auth",
  function($scope, $rootScope, Auth) {`

and then

`$scope.createUser = function(username, email, password) {
        $rootScope.usernames = username
        $scope.message = null;
        $scope.error = null;`

Comment: In the long run, you will want to learn how to use services instead of $rootScope. In the short run, you will want to make sure each of your views has a different controller.

Comment: Thankyou so much P Ackerman. Your a life saver It worked! Do you have any other suggestions to make? Im currently making a todo list website with a login/registration.

Comment: And if it dosent bother you P Ackerman do you know how to like implement a data for a specific user only? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

When your app changes routes, it destroys the scope of the old controller and creates a new scope. This happens even if you use the same controller for both the old and new route.

Store persistent data in your `Auth` factory along with the functions that create that data.

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var AuthObj = {};
    //Store persistent data on AuthObj
    AuthObj.ref = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
    AuthObj.createUser = function(email,password) {
        AuthObj.ref.createUser(
            {email: email, password: password },
            function(error, userData) {
                if (error) {
                    //process error
                } else {
                    //store data on AuthObj
                    AuthObj.userData = userData;
                }
             }
        );
        return AuthObj.userData;
    };
    //return AuthObj which holds functions and data
    return AuthObj;
  }
]);
```

Use your controller to **invoke** those functions and **retrieve** persistent data.

```
app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
  function($scope, Auth) {
     //retrieve userData
     $scope.userData = Auth.userData;
     $scope.createUser = function() {
          if ($scope.userData) {
              return;
          } else {
              $scope.userData =
                   //invoke function in factory
                   Auth.createUser($scope.email,$scope.password);
          };
     };
   }
]);
```

This way the data remain and persist when you change routes.

Comment: I am so confused on how to implement this to my code. Sorry for bieng dum

Comment: My goal when I write an answer is to create something that is useful to more than one reader. So when someone searches for say "AngularJS global variables", they get advice they can use. In this case the advice is --put persistent data in a **factory provider**. To learn more about **factory providers** see the [AngularJS Service Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Comment: I understand george but im not like understanding how to put prestiant data in your factory. Here is the working plunker i would love if you have an alternative that will help me in my future. Thankyou. http://plnkr.co/edit/qB3Gkeq5ji1YQyy0kpGH?p=preview

Comment: And in one of my seperate questions the login to that app is not working. I dont know why

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to the User view angular creates new instance of AuthCtrl controller, which mean new scope, that's why there are no value there.

Use services to share data (or even scope) between controllers.